# How to use custom domain on Laravel in Windows Server

Tags: php, laravel, windows

Am looking for an approach to dealing with the following issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have 3 **Laravel** applications running on a **windows server** with the server name "**php_apps**".
Each laravel application is served to a port. e.g;

```
php artisan serve --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0
php artisan serve --port 8002 --host 0.0.0.0
php artisan serve --port 8003 --host 0.0.0.0
```

And the URLs are `http://php_apps:8001`, `http://php_apps:8002`, and `http://php_apps:8003`

How do I replace the port numbers with names, to read something like; `http://php_apps/first_app`, `http://php_apps/second_app`, and `http://php_apps/third_app`

My aim is to replace the port numbers with something more descriptive and readable.

How best would you suggest I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Valet for windows](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows) :) Enjoy